# How can I get org-protocol to work with Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, protocol

I am using org-mode in Emacs, and can successfully use org-protocol with Firefox, that is, the following

```
org-protocol://store-link://http:google.com//google
```

successfully works in Firefox, after completing the question as to what program (`emacsclientw`) to associate.

#### Question: I would like this to work in Internet Explorer.

The registry was edited via double-clicking on a file with contents

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol]
@="URL:Org Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\org-protocol\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Programme\\Emacs\\emacs\\bin\\emacsclientw.exe\" \"%1\""
```

These steps are from [org-protocol_el – Intercept calls from emacsclient to trigger custom actions](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html).

I tried adding line

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shell\URLProtocols\org-protocol]
```

from [Custom URL Protocol in Windows CE « The Gray Zone](http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/2010/08/custom-url-protocol-in-windows-ce/), but I am flailing; this did not work. I am trying to avoid a wall of information at Microsoft sites.

Comment: Why was this downvoted, seems legit on this site